# Accessing global variable in a class

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie and new user there, and I want to ask

```
an_ac rtc(width);
class js_jam{
  private:
  unsigned long uj = millis();
  uint8_t speed;
  public:
  void update_jam(){
     Time now = rtc.getTime; // PROBLEM HERE
     uint8_t jam = now.hour;
  } 
};
```

when I try to access 'rtc' inside 'js_jam' class, I get the following error

> invalid use of non-static member function

Can you explain why?

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`an_ac rtc` is accessible to your class like you wrote, but if you're calling a member function, then you need to add `()` to it like this:

```
rtc.getTime()
```